# How do I create a choropleth map in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, choropleth

How do I create a choropleth map using the pandas data frame below?

```
df.head()
Postal  Code   Latitude   Longitude  Average Price
0        M1B  43.806686  -79.194353  $880,124
1        M1C  43.784535  -79.160497  $1,416,183
2        M1E  43.763573  -79.188711  $1,081,779
3        M1G  43.770992  -79.216917  $912,943
4        M1H  43.773136  -79.239476  $929,923
```

What is the best way to create a map using this data?

Comment: I have no idea but I found this https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/ check "Using GeoPandas Data Frames"

Answer (score 0):

There are several map visualization libraries available in python. As an example, I will present a combination of [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example-with-plotly-express) and mapbox. This requires getting the APIkey for [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
"Postal  Code"   Latitude   Longitude  "Average Price"
0        M1B  43.806686  -79.194353  $880,124
1        M1C  43.784535  -79.160497  $1,416,183
2        M1E  43.763573  -79.188711  $1,081,779
3        M1G  43.770992  -79.216917  $912,943
4        M1H  43.773136  -79.239476  $929,923
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['Average Price'] = df['Average Price'].str.replace(',','').str.replace('$','').astype(int)

import plotly.express as px
px.set_mapbox_access_token(open("mapbox_API_key.txt").read())

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", color="Average Price", size="Average Price",
                  color_continuous_scale=px.colors.cyclical.IceFire, size_max=15, zoom=10)
fig.show()
```

[image]